# Do Receive addresses generated by blockchain.info's wallet expire with time?

Tags: blockchain.info, receiving

Sender sent me BTC yesterday. I am expecting a deposit to my blockchain.info wallet but that has not happened in the past 20 hours.

I didn't give the sender my public address, but the receive address generated by the "Receive" button on the wallet.

Do those addresses expire? I gave the Receive addresses 6-8 weeks ago. Is it possible that the addresses generated by "Receive" button expire in 6-8 weeks time?

If so, can BTC sent to an expired Receive address be recovered?

Comment: Can you tell us the receive address or the transaction id?

Comment: Here are the three transaction nummbers.

Comment: confirmations:

Bitcoin transaction ID:
80464c1128267b8634041182aedcd23aad4611219e1722f19ee1f9ad169fce4a

Bitcoin transaction ID:
b3334318bf1a3c934cd33a6d1a9e4cff25407a94d194bc5d5190fe7e8edddc69

Bitcoin transaction ID:
fcf28f47260635952ab8ca33ae5658fc54cc75532d0ebe5e0e5aa926b84a1a16

Comment: I checked these transactions, and didn't found any. Are these transaction ID's send by the sender? Then there can be a chance that the sender is scamming you.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the tx numbers. I put one of them into cypher?????.com which recognized it but returned tech info that i was not able to interpret.

Comment: @asterisk, SE inserted spaces in txids, https://blockchain.info/tx/80464c1128267b8634041182aedcd23aad4611219e1722f19ee1f9ad169fce4a https://blockchain.info/tx/b3334318bf1a3c934cd33a6d1a9e4cff25407a94d194bc5d5190fe7e8edddc69 https://blockchain.info/tx/fcf28f47260635952ab8ca33ae5658fc54cc75532d0ebe5e0e5aa926b84a1a16 are confirmed

Answer (score 1):

Addresses do not expire, regardless of the wallet that generated them.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Chow is correct in that addresses don't expire.

However, when a 3rd party service generates a receiving address for your account, you're relying on them to continue monitoring that address over time and assign received funds to the balance of your user account. **It's reasonably likely they won't monitor the address forever for every address they've ever issued, which effectively means they expire. How and when that happens is up to the service involved.**

This kind of issue is one of the trade-offs with using a 3rd party wallet or account rather than running your own wallet and keeping full control of your private keys.

There is at least one other case where an address is no longer realistically usable, which is when the private key is known by someone else. In that case funds sent to the address won't reliably stay there. In your situation, this doesn't really apply though.